# SDK not registering (from non view constructor, not an onCreate()) - No errors

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

I am making a cleaner version of a research drone android app that utilises DJI SDK/Hardware and attempting to structure the app more appropriately such that it can be expanded later. The application allows user selection of hardware (currently mock/test, DJI and ToDo) from a config pop up in the main display (class UserInterface extends AppCompatActivity). This is to allow the app to be used without registering or check perms when it is not being used for DJI. Previously I registered the DJI SDK when the app first opens, but it was my first real app and was a mess to follow its flow and didn't manage screen real estate very well.

When the DJI option is actioned from the pop up "config" window on the main interface from UI class, the UI class saves the config to a SettingsManager instance and calls the EventsManager instance with method runSettings(). The method actions the relevant SDK by try/catch{new DJI SDK class} and passes both the instances of EventsManager and UI.

The difference of this major version compared to my first version (which functions correctly) is the API key (changed package name, so new key), I am not doing the SDK registration in the first main activity and the SDK registration is not a viewable class, it only forwards strings to run on UI thread for showToast method in the UI class.

- App does not return any errors.
- showToast for messages in the DJI SDK class appear on the display but nothing inside the
  SDKManagerCallback occurs.
- Unsure of constructor in a class with extends AppCompatActivity, context methods seem unavailable when
  tried with different class extensions.
- I have tried creating two DJI developer keys, no difference.
- Unsure of DJI class listing in Manifest as it is not an activity started by an intent with bundle but
  does require context.
- DJI SDK class is extracted from DJISDKDemo (I am fairly new to android app development, not sure I
  could write my own version from the limited explanation on DJI dev site).

Thank you greatly for your help and any other tips appreciated.

The SDKRegistration class:

```js
package com.research.droneapp; // mock package name for SO

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import dji.common.error.DJIError;
import dji.common.error.DJISDKError;
import dji.sdk.base.BaseComponent;
import dji.sdk.base.BaseProduct;
import dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKInitEvent;
import dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager;

public class SoftwareDevelopmentKitDJI extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "SoftwareDevelopmentKit";

    public UserInterface userInterface;
    public EventsManager eventsManager;

    public static final String FLAG_CONNECTION_CHANGE = "dji_sdk_connection_change";
    private static BaseProduct mProduct;
    private Handler mHandler;

    public boolean isConnected = false; // Variable for start up flag

    private static final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSION_LIST = new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.VIBRATE,
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
    };
    private List<String> missingPermission = new ArrayList<>();
    private AtomicBoolean isRegistrationInProgress = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 12345;

    public SoftwareDevelopmentKitDJI(UserInterface userInterface, EventsManager eventsManager) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SoftwareDevelopmentKitDJI");
        this.userInterface = userInterface;
        this.eventsManager = eventsManager;

        // Permission checked true actions SDK registration
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkAndRequestPermissions();
        }

        // Handle DJI SDK hardware changes in background thread??
        // ToDo: Receive hardware changes in EventsManager
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    /**
     * Checks if there is any missing permissions, and
     * requests runtime permission if needed.
     */
    private void checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        Log.d(TAG, "checkAndRequestPermissions: S");
        // Check for permissions
        for (String eachPermission : REQUIRED_PERMISSION_LIST) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(userInterface, eachPermission) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                missingPermission.add(eachPermission);
            }
        }
        // Request for missing permissions
        if (missingPermission.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "notMissingPerms");
            startSDKRegistration();
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Log.d(TAG, "missingPerms");
            passToastToUI("Need permissions!");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(userInterface,
                    missingPermission.toArray(new String[missingPermission.size()]),
                    REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "checkAndRequestPermissions: E");
    }

    /**
     * Result of runtime permission request
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        // Check for granted permission and remove from missing list
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            for (int i = grantResults.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    missingPermission.remove(permissions[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        // If no missing permission, start SDK registration
        if (missingPermission.isEmpty()) {
            startSDKRegistration();
        } else {
            passToastToUI("Missing permissions!!!");
        }
    }

    private void startSDKRegistration() {
        Log.d(TAG, "startSDKRegistration: S");
        if (isRegistrationInProgress.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    passToastToUI("registering, pls wait...");
                    Log.d(TAG, "startSDKRegistration: run");

                    // ToDO: Investigate why SDKManagerCallback's don't occur
                    //  (is getApplicationContext() correct?)
                    DJISDKManager.getInstance().registerApp(getApplicationContext(),
                            new DJISDKManager.SDKManagerCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRegister(DJIError djiError) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onRegister: S");
                            if (djiError == DJISDKError.REGISTRATION_SUCCESS) {
                                passToastToUI("Register Success");
                                DJISDKManager.getInstance().startConnectionToProduct();
                            }
                            else {
                                passToastToUI("Register sdk failed!");
                            }
                            Log.v(TAG, djiError.getDescription());
                            Log.d(TAG, "onRegister: E");
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onProductDisconnect() {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onProductDisconnect");
                            passToastToUI("Product Disconnected");
                            notifyStatusChange();
                            isConnected = false;        // Set hardware connection flag
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onProductConnect(BaseProduct baseProduct) {
                            Log.d(TAG, String.format("onProductConnect newProduct:%s", baseProduct));
                            passToastToUI("Product Connected");
                            notifyStatusChange();
                            isConnected = true;         // Set hardware connection flag
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onComponentChange(BaseProduct.ComponentKey componentKey, BaseComponent oldComponent,
                                                      BaseComponent newComponent) {
                            if (newComponent != null) {
                                newComponent.setComponentListener(new BaseComponent.ComponentListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onConnectivityChange(boolean isConnected) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "onComponentConnectivityChanged: " + isConnected);
                                        notifyStatusChange();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            Log.d(TAG, String.format(
                                    "onComponentChange key:%s, oldComponent:%s, newComponent:%s",
                                            componentKey, oldComponent, newComponent));
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onInitProcess(DJISDKInitEvent djisdkInitEvent, int i) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "startSDKRegistration: onInitProcess");
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onDatabaseDownloadProgress(long l, long l1) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "startSDKRegistration: onDatabaseDownloadProgress");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "startSDKRegistration: E");
    }

    private void notifyStatusChange() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(updateRunnable);
        mHandler.postDelayed(updateRunnable, 500);
    }

    private Runnable updateRunnable = () -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(FLAG_CONNECTION_CHANGE);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    };

    private void passToastToUI(String toastMsg) {
        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            userInterface.showToast(toastMsg);
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.research.droneapp"> <!-- mock package name for SO -->

    <!-- Permissions and features -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- App Activity Process -->
    <application
        android:name="com.research.droneapp.MApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/hmu_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/hmu_icon_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

        <!-- Main Display -->
        <activity android:name="com.research.droneapp.UserInterface" />

        <!-- DJI SDK -->
        <uses-library android:name="com.android.future.usb.accessory" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.dji.sdk.API_KEY"
            android:value="*************" /> <!-- removed for SO -->

        <activity
            android:name="dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJIAoaControllerActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
        </activity>

        <service android:name="dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJIGlobalService">
        </service>

        <activity android:name="com.research.droneapp.SoftwareDevelopmentKitDJI" />

        <!-- Splash Screen at Launch -->
        <activity android:name="com.research.droneapp.Splash" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The method that starts the SDK class:

```js
    /**
     * Settings changes to start relevant classes
     */
    public void runSettings() {
        Log.d(TAG, "runSettings: S");
                                                            // Get hardware selection from settings
        int hardwarePosition = settingsManager.getHardwareInt();

        /*ToDo: Set Test Environment*/
        if (hardwarePosition == 0) {                        // Operate settings for test environment
            Log.d(TAG, "runSettings: hardPos Test");
            userInterface.showToast("runSetting: TEST");
        }
        else if (hardwarePosition == 1) {                   // Operate settings for DJI
            Log.d(TAG, "runSettings: hardPos MavP2");
            try {
                this.softwareDevelopmentKitDJI = new SoftwareDevelopmentKitDJI(
                        userInterface, this);
                Log.d(TAG, "runSettings: DJI Launched");
                userInterface.showToast("runSetting: DJI");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "runSettings: DJI Error: "+ e.toString());
                userInterface.showToast("runSetting: Error");
            }
        }                                                   // Operate settings for...?
        else if (hardwarePosition == 2) { /*ToDo*/
            Log.d(TAG, "runSettings: hardPos ToDo");
            userInterface.showToast("runSetting: ToDo");
        }
        else {                                              // Unknown hardware
            Log.d(TAG, "runSettings: Error");
            userInterface.showToast("runSetting:Error");
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "runSettings: E");
    }
```

The config window click listener for action changes button, within the method of UI class for config pop up window:

```js
// Action changes
        Button btnAction = popupView.findViewById(R.id.btnAction);
        btnAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "displayConfigOverlay: onClick -> configAction");
                
                // Update hardware setting
                String hardware =
                        (btnTest.isChecked())?settingsManager.HARDWARE_OPTIONS[0]:
                        (btnMavP2.isChecked())?settingsManager.HARDWARE_OPTIONS[1]:
                        (btnToDo.isChecked())?settingsManager.HARDWARE_OPTIONS[2]:
                                "NoSelection!";
                settingsManager.setHardware(hardware);

                // Update port number
                String port = serverPortEdit.getText().toString();
                settingsManager.setServerPort(port);

                // Update WSS launch setting
                boolean autoLunchWSS = swAutoWSS.isChecked();
                settingsManager.setAutoLaunchWSS(autoLunchWSS);

                // Display to user
                showToast("Hardware: " + hardware + "\nPort: " + port + "\nAutoWSS: " +
                        autoLunchWSS);

                // Push settings
                eventsManager.runSettings();

                // Close config pop up
                popupConfig.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Apologises for the lack of and mixed commenting styles. Again any tips appreciated, still new to android and java.

Answer (score 0):

Min API23 setting in gradle allowed code to run but did not allow SDK to download. Unsure why errors not returned.

Solved by changing gradle to following:

```js
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
...
```

Additionally found a potential context issue within layout, tools:context="..." was not set to the Activity interacting with this layout.

```html
...
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".UserInterface" >
...
```